# Rigging problems afoot

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, armature, bones

I'm totally a rigging noob, so I followed this quick and easy tutorial to rig my cartoony 3D model, and it was all peaches and cream for now, until i parented the model with the armature. The feet twist unnaturally just by connecting the armature, without even moving the mesh. Everything else seems just fine, as far as movement and weighting goes, but the feet! I took a few screenshots before and after connecting the armatures together, and I really want to get this fixed. I tried adding loop edges, resizing, adjusting the position of the foot armatures, nothing is working. I also read about Ctrl+a -> Scale, which I tried, and its not fixing the problem either. I don't know what else to do. I don't want to be a rigging nooblet forever!

Will I have to remake the mesh or the armature at all?[![][1]Before rigging][1]

[[image]After rigging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR5Eg.png)

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it! I checked the bones again after I checked another thread and fixed the bones' rotatopn to 0 (it was set to values like 90, and 177.23 or so) and it realigned the feet. I must have rotated them while building the armature by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, fixed it! I checked the bones again after I checked another thread and fixed the bones' rotatopn to 0 (it was set to values like 90, and 177.23 or so) and it realigned the feet. I must have rotated them while building the armature by accident.

(how do I mark this as Answered...?)

Comment: If you solved it, add that to the question or delete the question.